# How to become root in gcloud compute engine via ssh?

Tags: gcloud

I need to install a program in gcloud environment. When I ssh, however, I need to become root to use yum, but I never set a root password. Is there a default password set?

Also, I see different file systems when I login via ssh from commandline or using ssh button at the browser int the "Compute Engine" site.

Answer (score 2):

`sudo su`

This is just some text that SO wants from me. Sometimes, a short answer is actually the best answer. Hey SO: When your Spouse said 'yes', did you also expect them to ramble on to fill 30 characters?